# jboss 5.1 does not work after redirect from HTTP to HTTPS connection

Tags: ssl, https, jboss5.x

the jboss server does not work if redirect to HTTPS url(port 8443), and here is WAR package web.xml configuration:

```
 <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>HtmlAdaptor</web-resource-name>
   <description>Security for all users</description>
   <url-pattern>/all/*</url-pattern>
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
   <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>role01</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
     <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

if i change

```
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```

to

```
<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
```

the server can accept HTTP request at 8081 port.

what configurations should i pay attention for SSL connection? 
any additional configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are different configuration about server.xml between jboss4.x and jboss5.x: 
former server.xml on jboss4.x:

```
  <Connector port="8443" address="{jboss.bind.address}"
       maxThreads="100" strategy="ms" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
```

it should be as below on jboss5.x:

```
  <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
        port="8443" address="{jboss.bind.address}"
       maxThreads="100" strategy="ms" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
```

SSLEnabled is necessary for jboss5.x